# Length of nearest neighbor path in travel salesman problem

Tags: pr.probability, graph-theory, mg.metric-geometry, geometric-probability

Given $n$ nodes uniformly distributed in $[0,1]^2$, consider the nearest neighbor algorithm to solve traveling salesman problem, i.e., each time I select the nearest neighbor not visited so far as the next node to visit, my question is: what is the expected length of such TSP tour?

Answer (score 6):

A careful experimental analysis of the nearest-neighbor (NN) heuristic (among other heuristics) is described in this paper:

> Johnson, David S., and Lyle A. McGeoch. "The traveling salesman problem: A case study in local optimization." *Local search in combinatorial optimization* 1 (1997): 215-310.
>   ([PDF download link](http://www.csc.kth.se/utbildning/kth/kurser/DD2440/avalg14/TSP-JohMcg97.pdf).)

They find that the growth rate, in comparison to the Karp-Held lower bound, 
"appears to be proportional to $\log n$" for "random distance matrices."
This is the theoretical growth rate w.r.t. the optimum.
In contrast, for "random Euclidean instances" up to $n=10^6$, they find 
(Table 1, p.15) that the NN heuristic
leads to paths nearly constantly about 25% longer than the Karp-Held lower bound.
This is closer (but not identical) to the OP's "uniformly distributed within $[0,1]^2$."
The section, "Standard Test Instances" on pp.12-14 unpacks
"random Euclidean instances."

Incidentally, the observed running time grows subquadratically.

(See also the follow-up MO question, 
"[Travelling Salesman Problem: Can the nearest neighbor algorithm be n times longer than the optimal solution?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/210175/6094).")